# How to include listing language in top right corner of the listing?

Tags: listings

I'm using the `listings` package, both using `\begin{lstlistings}` and using `\lstinputlisting` commands. Now, I would like to display the language of the listing for some languages. Say I have the following code:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, hidelinks]{report}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{listings, xcolor}
\lstdefinelanguage{Toml}{
    comment = [l]{\#},
    keywords = {true, false},
    morestring = [b]{"}
}
\lstset{
    tabsize = 2,
    frame = tb,
    breaklines = true,
    numbers = left,
    numbersep = 5pt,
    numberstyle = \color{white!30!black}\scriptsize,
    stepnumber = 1,
    basicstyle = \footnotesize\ttfamily,
    commentstyle={\color{green!50!black}\ttfamily},
    keywordstyle = {\bfseries\color{purple}}, % keywords
    keywordstyle = [2]{\itshape\color{blue}}, % traits
    keywordstyle = [3]{\color{blue}}, % primitive types
    keywordstyle = [4]{\color{blue}}, % type and value ctors
    keywordstyle = [5]{\color{purple!50!blue}}, % macros
    stringstyle = \color{green!45!blue},
    aboveskip = \baselineskip,
    showstringspaces = false
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Toml]
[package]
name = "foobar"
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

I'd like the string `TOML` to be written in small, grey letters in the right corner below the first horizontal line.

If possible, I'd like to enable this only for certain languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use `tcolorbox`.

**Edit**: using both an environment (like `lstlisting`) and a command (like `lstinputlisting`).

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, hidelinks]{report}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{listings, xcolor}
\usepackage[listings,skins]{tcolorbox}
\lstdefinelanguage{Toml}{
    comment = [l]{\#},
    keywords = {true, false},
    morestring = [b]{"}
}
\lstset{
    tabsize = 2,
    frame = tb,
    breaklines = true,
    numbers = left,
    numbersep = 5pt,
    numberstyle = \color{white!30!black}\scriptsize,
    stepnumber = 1,
    basicstyle = \footnotesize\ttfamily,
    commentstyle={\color{green!50!black}\ttfamily},
    keywordstyle = {\bfseries\color{purple}}, % keywords
    keywordstyle = [2]{\itshape\color{blue}}, % traits
    keywordstyle = [3]{\color{blue}}, % primitive types
    keywordstyle = [4]{\color{blue}}, % type and value ctors
    keywordstyle = [5]{\color{purple!50!blue}}, % macros
    stringstyle = \color{green!45!blue},
    aboveskip = \baselineskip,
    showstringspaces = false
}

\newtcblisting{mylisting}[1]{%
    enhanced,
    listing only,
    title={\texttt{#1}},
    attach boxed title to top right,
    listing options={language=#1}
}

\newtcbinputlisting{\myinputlisting}[2][]{%
    listing file={#2},
    enhanced,
    listing only,
    title={\scriptsize\texttt{#1}},
    attach boxed title to top right={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
    listing options={language={#1}},
    coltitle=black,
    colbacktitle=gray!10
}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Toml]
    [package]
    name = "foobar"
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{mylisting}{Toml}
    [package]
    name = "foobar"
\end{mylisting}

\begin{filecontents*}{code.toml}
    [package]
    name = "foobar"
\end{filecontents*}
\myinputlisting[Toml]{code.toml} % <-- replace code.toml with your file
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to also use `mylisting` with `\lstinputlisting`? Also, can the box be re-styled to look more similar to the original? I'd like the language marker to be a little more subtle

Comment: Sure, see my edited answer.